# reg-ex to scrape a price

Tags: regex, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a price, im struggling writing some reg ex to grab the specific text

```
<option value="1">
                        1 


                                (£&nbsp;70)


                    </option>
```

Prices are pretty much displayed like the above in the source code with lots of white space. ideally I would like to grap the 70 from the string

this is what I have so far

```
preg_match("/<option value=\"1\">(.+)<\/option>/siU", $html, $matches);
```

I half expected this to grab   **1(£ 70)**, but it did not work, any help?

Comment: You need to read the first answer to this infamous SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it [*does*](http://www.ideone.com/PkAnd) match. Problem is (probably) that the match contains a bunch of whitespace characters:

```
string(97) "
                        1 


                                (£&nbsp;70)


                    "
```

**Edit**
You can do a [little sanitizing](http://www.ideone.com/1Ov91):

```
$matches[1] = preg_replace('/\s+/s', ' ', trim($matches[1]));
```

Gives:

```
string(14) "1 (£&nbsp;70)"
```

Comment: is this an answer or a comment to my answer? :)

Comment: @duedl0r This is an answer to the question ... well, sort of. I was trying to show that the regex *did* actually match something, and subsequently tried to make the result match OPs expectations.

Answer (score 0):

```
/<option value=\"1\">(.*?\((.*?)\).*?<\/option>/
```

also make sure you're testing your string without newlines ([pattern modifiers](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php))

you may also want to consider using an xml parser.